# ImageView Animation Repeatition

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I am working on an application which needs animations with imageView.
At starting the position of image is at CGPoint(735,112),on clicking the animation button it has to move to the left of the screen ie to point CGPoint(20,112) and hast to  repeat the animation from left to right i.e to point CGPoint(735,112),has to stop after this. i am using the following Code.

```
CGRect newRect=cleanStrip.frame;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation1" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
newRect.origin.x=20;
cleanStrip.frame=newRect;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

After repeating the animation the image view has to stop at it original position CGPoint(735,112).But the above code stops the image at CGPoint(20,112).

How can i stop the image at its original position after animation. 
Thanks,

Comment: What is the code for your animation1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use block to start your animation

```
__block CGRect newRect=cleanStrip.frame;
__block int originx = newRect.origin.x;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
             animations:^{
                 newRect.origin.x=20;
                 cleanStrip.frame=newRect;
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                                  animations:^{
                                       newRect.origin.x=originx ;
                                       cleanStrip.frame=newRect;
                                  }];

             }];
```

Comment: It has to repeat the animation to original postion and Stop.

Comment: newRect.origin.x=20; line showing error that "ReadOnly Variable is not assignable"

Comment: currently, i don't have a mac os x, i can't test, you can try the new edited

Comment: I hav some other questions on animations, cani i ask?